# If condition, store previous df column value, without loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

is it possible to retrieve previous column value without loop in pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'a': [True, False, False, True, True, False], 'b': [0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4]})

df
Out[427]: 
       a  b
0   True  0
1  False  0
2  False  0
3   True  3
4   True  4
5  False  4
```

###### If df['a'] = True, store index, else previous value

```
# Attempt 1
df['c'] = np.where(df['a'], df.index, df['c'].shift(1))


# Attempt 2
df['c'] = df.index
df['c'] = np.where(df['a'], df['c'], df['c'].shift(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) on the index converted [`to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) after masking the non-True values:

```
df['b'] = df.index.to_series().where(df['a']).ffill(downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
       a  b
0   True  0
1  False  0
2  False  0
3   True  3
4   True  4
5  False  4
```